# How to display notification like this or with IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

How to display notification like Quality Time. I use the below code to display notification but it give me IllegalArgumentException: Invalid importance level

[image]

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
// Create the channel for the notification
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name,
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED);

// Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setAutoCancel(true);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(
        this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

Notification notification = builder.build();
startForeground(1, notification);
```

Get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid importance level 
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.createNotificati‌onChannels(INotifica‌tionManager.java:155‌6)
at android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannels(N‌otificationManager.j‌ava:453) 
at android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(No‌tificationManager.ja‌va:441) 
at com.app.MyService.onCreate(ScreenService.java:167) –
Add Comment Collapse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN`

> IMPORTANCE_MIN
>
> added in API level 24
> int IMPORTANCE_MIN
> Only shows in the shade, below the fold.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#IMPORTANCE_MIN

Comment: Hi, yes it is showing below the fold with importance min. But we want to use a small minimized notification like Quality time. Any ideas how we can do that?

Comment: @AvinashShinde did you find out how to create minimized notification?

Comment: @patonjo yes. please refer above answer. I am starting notification form my fragment. Previously I tried to start from service so it didn't work.